# asignador en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de un asignador de Tareas para 2 trabajadores. Cada trabajador debe asignarse en un área. Se trabaja con mysql 5

Mi tabla Tarea tiene: id (autoincremental), area, tarea y trabajador.
Por ejemplo, debería quedar así, cada trabajador en un área:

**Área     |  Tarea             |    Trabajador**

RRHH     |  asistencia personal  |  Trabajador1

RRHH      | realizar liquidaciones |    Trabajador1

Contable    | realizar declaraciones |Trabajador2

Gerencia|    planificar agenda   |   Trabajador1

Logistica|   planificar pedidos   |  Trabajador2

Logistica|   contratar proveedores| Trabajador2

Esto he estado realizando, he declarado una variable para generar un ranking agrupado por área pero el resultado me asigna todo a Trabajador1, Por favor, alguna sugerencia, no encuentro forma de asignar un Trabajador por área??

```html
$sql = "SELECT id,area, count(*),@rn :=d( @rn+1 ) AS rank,trabajador  FROM dbempresa.tareas, (SELECT @rn:=0) a group BY area";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $cantidad = $result -> num_rows;
 while ($row = $result -> fetch_array()){
      for ($i=1;$i<$cantidad;$i=$i+2){
        $consulta="UPDATE dbempresa.tareas  SET trabajador=concat('Trabajador','1')where @rn=$i";
                    $resulta = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
                    $consulta="UPDATE dbempresa.tareas  SET trabajador=concat('Trabajador','2') where @rn=('$i'+1)";
                    $resulta = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);}}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que partes de una situación como ésta:

```
+--------------+------------------------+------------+
| area_trabajo | tarea                  | trabajador |
+--------------+------------------------+------------+
| RRHH         | Asistencia personal    | NULL       |
| RRHH         | Realizar liquidaciones | NULL       |
| Contable     | Realizar declaraciones | NULL       |
| Gerencial    | Planificar agenda      | NULL       |
| Logística    | Planificar pedidos     | NULL       |
| Logística    | Contratar proveedores  | NULL       |
+--------------+------------------------+------------+
```

En la que debes asignar una serie de tareas a una serie de trabajadores, manteniendo a cada uno de éstos en un área de trabajo concreta.

Para ello, te sugiero normalizar un poco tu modelo, obteniendo algo así:

[image: Modelo normalizado]

Para lo que puedes usar estas instrucciones:

```
CREATE TABLE areas(
  id_area int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  area_trabajo varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE trabajadores(
  id_trabajador int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  trabajador varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE tareas(
  id_tarea int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  tarea varchar(31),
  id_area int,
  id_trabajador int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_area) REFERENCES areas(id_area),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_trabajador) REFERENCES trabajadores(id_trabajador)
  );
INSERT INTO areas (area_trabajo) VALUES
  ('RRHH'),('Contable'),('Gerencial'),('Logística');
INSERT INTO trabajadores (trabajador) VALUES
  ('Trabajador1'),('Trabajador2');
INSERT INTO tareas (tarea, id_area) VALUES
  ('Asistencia personal',1),
  ('Realizar liquidaciones',1),
  ('Realizar declaraciones',2),
  ('Planificar agenda',3),
  ('Planificar pedidos',4),
  ('Contratar proveedores',4);
```

Puesto que cada trabajador debe estar asignado a un área, relacionaría directamente estas dos entidades con:

```
ALTER TABLE areas ADD id_trabajador int,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_trabajador) REFERENCES trabajadores(id_trabajador);
```

Obteniendo el diagrama:

[image: Modelo con un trabajador por área]

Nótese que, tal y como indica tu ejemplo, asumo que en cada área únicamente habrá un trabajador y un mismo trabajador puede trabajar en diferentes áreas.

Por lo que únicamente queda realizar las asignaciones de áreas a cada trabajador haciendo uso de la función módulo:

```
UPDATE areas JOIN (
    SELECT id_area,MOD(id_area+1,(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trabajadores
      ))+1 id_trabajador
      FROM areas  
  ) c1 USING(id_area)
  set areas.id_trabajador = c1.id_trabajador;
```

Para que esto funcione, no debe haber huecos en los autoincrementales, para lo que te sugiero usar otro campo que tú te encargues de renumerar antes de realizar la asignación y así evites sorpresas.

```
ALTER TABLE trabajadores ADD n_trabajador int;
ALTER TABLE areas ADD n_area int;

SET @n:=0;
UPDATE trabajadores JOIN (
    SELECT id_trabajador,@n:=@n+1 n_trabajador
      FROM trabajadores
      ORDER BY id_trabajador  
  ) c1 USING(id_trabajador)
  SET trabajadores.n_trabajador = c1.n_trabajador;

SET @n:=0;
UPDATE areas JOIN (
    SELECT id_area,@n:=@n+1 n_area
      FROM areas
      ORDER BY id_area  
  ) c1 USING(id_area)
  SET areas.n_area = c1.n_area;
```

Con este campo alternativo al `id` creado, ya podemos hacer la asignación de áreas sin errores:

```
UPDATE areas JOIN (
    SELECT n_area,id_trabajador FROM (
        SELECT n_area,MOD(n_area+1,(
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trabajadores
          ))+1 n_trabajador
          FROM areas   
      ) c1 JOIN trabajadores USING(n_trabajador) 
  ) c2 USING(n_area)
  set areas.id_trabajador = c2.id_trabajador;
```

Una cosa más, dado que el trabajador depende del área, sería conveniente desvincular al trabajador de la tarea, ya que se puede obtener el trabajador asignado a través de su área, evitando generar ese bucle de redundancia:

```
ALTER TABLE tareas
  DROP FOREIGN KEY tareas_ibfk_2,
  DROP id_trabajador;
```

Dejando el diagrama de la base de datos así:

[image: Modelo correctamente normalizado]

Y llegando al resultado:

```
+--------------+------------------------+-------------+
| area_trabajo | tarea                  | trabajador  |
+--------------+------------------------+-------------+
| RRHH         | Asistencia personal    | Trabajador1 |
| RRHH         | Realizar liquidaciones | Trabajador1 |
| Contable     | Realizar declaraciones | Trabajador2 |
| Gerencial    | Planificar agenda      | Trabajador1 |
| Logística    | Planificar pedidos     | Trabajador2 |
| Logística    | Contratar proveedores  | Trabajador2 |
+--------------+------------------------+-------------+
```

Con la consulta:

```
SELECT area_trabajo,tarea,trabajador
  FROM tareas
  JOIN areas USING(id_area)
  JOIN trabajadores USING(id_trabajador);
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil, sobre todo por la parte en la que parto de un modelo que no se ajusta a la realidad para terminar llegando al que debería haber sido el de partida. A veces, invertir un rato haciendo el modelo ER merece la pena para no dar tantas vueltas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.